# Need help on Beginning HL7

Tags: hl7

hI 
Can anyone please guide me to Creating HL7 Version 3 messages for the first time. I need to understand the design of XML based HL7v 3  message. I want to design an interface engine in Java. Have tried to find.. but cannot see anything for beginners. 
Please help

Comment: "I want to design an interface engine in Java"... just to help stop wheel-reinvention where possible, have you taken a look at Mirth Connect?

Answer (score 2):

HL-7 documentation has to be purchased from [hl7.org](http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/v3messages.cfm). They control copyright and so legal free copies aren't available AFAIK.

If you feel thrifty and are willing to work out some of the information yourself, the [HAPI project](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/) might be a good place to start. If you look at the code you can see how some of the different segments are represented.

Comment: +1 for HAPI library - it is used in OSCAR McMaster for parsing HL7 labs.

Comment: HL7 members are looking to use StackOverflow for more of its support queries. To aide that could someone create a hl7-v3 tag and use it for this question.

Answer (score 1):

There's a tool I've been using lately that helped me on that. It's called [HL7 Soup](http://www.hl7soup.com/)  which is a HL7 Viewer.

It's advantage over other products I used is it's easier to understand messages and its structure, which helped me learning lots about HL7.